# Using cin in C++

Tags: c++, char, cin

I'd like to use cin and I used char for the int type (do you call it like that?)  and it just shows one letter of what typed.  How can I get the whole sentence?

Comment: not a CPP for a long time, but I believe you want `char*` and not `char`

Comment: Better yet, `std::string`.  Telling `cin` to get a `std::string` makes it read a line (sort of like `fgets` in C), if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @Joey : Not a line, only a word. `getline` must be used to get an entire line.

Comment: It would be much easier to understand what you're saying if you showed the actual code.

Comment: hm not really cuz im just trying and wanted to know how cin works...

Comment: @Hikari Iwasaki : Well, "it just shows" probably means you did write some code.

Comment: oh that code!  
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
  char a;
  cin >> a;
  cout << a;
}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're using c++ why not use `std::string` instead? Something like this should do what you're looking for:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  using namespace std;
  string sentence;
  cout << "Enter a sentence -> ";
  getline(cin, sentence);
  cout << "You entered: " << sentence << endl;
}
```

Comment: My sentence are usually long and span more than one line, I may even break them up into multiple parts with punctuation so they will definitely be longer than a single line; In fact I don't remember, because it was probably in play school,  the last time I wrote a real sentence that was short enough to fit on a single line.

Answer (score 2):

use cin.getline()

```
char name[256];
cout << "What is your name?\n>";
cin.getline(name, 256);

cout << "Your name is " << name;
```

Comment: This is correct, but in C++ it's probably a better idea to be using `std::string` and the free function `std::getline` instead of raw character arrays, as they're significantly safer and less error-prone

Comment: @templatetypedef TBH, I've not used C++ since I had to in school, and even then I think I always used std::string. Just trying to help, haha.